# Print Meta Data In Woocomerce Rest Api

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to woocomerce Rest API. I am accessing all data from wordpress. Now i want to print the meta data. Api return me data in this json :-

```
[meta_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 53380
                            [key] => slide_template
                            [value] => default
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 53381
                            [key] => payment_details
                            [value] => no data found
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 53382
                            [key] => wf_invoice_number
                            [value] => CNC04216
                        )
              )
```

After decoding of json i want to print this meta data.
I am trying to print like this

```
<?php  echo $std[$k]['meta_data'][2]->wf_invoice_number; ?>
```

But may be its not a std Class object...
How can i echo the meta data values.

Comment: perhaps `echo $std[$k]['meta_data'][2]['key'];`

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: wf_invoice_number .... but it has a data in this key....

Comment: `wf_invoice_number` is the data stored in that entity rather than the key by which to access

Comment: After doing print_r ($std[$k]["meta_data"]) , it show me data like this [7] => Array ( [id] => 50048 [key] => payment_details [value] => paid ) ) ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear what your problem is exactly - it seems that you have the values and the keys mixed up

The data from the question can be represented with this PHP snippet

```
$data=array(
    'meta_data'=>array(
        array('id'=>53380,'key'=>'slide_template','value'=>'default'),
        array('id'=>53381,'key'=>'payment_details','value'=>'no data found'),
        array('id'=>53382,'key'=>'wf_invoice_number','value'=>'CNC04216'),
    )
);
```

To show details from all parts yo can iterate through the top level array like this and access the items within using standard array notation.

```
foreach( $data['meta_data'] as $arr ){
    printf(
        '<pre>
            id: %s
            key: %s
            value: %s
        </pre>',
        $arr['id'],
        $arr['key'],
        $arr['value']
    );
}
```

This will output:

```
<pre>
    id: 53380
    key: slide_template
    value: default
</pre>
<pre>
    id: 53381
    key: payment_details
    value: no data found
</pre>
<pre>
    id: 53382
    key: wf_invoice_number
    value: CNC04216
</pre>
```

To access a specific record by index ( using the quoted index of 2 for instance )

```
#specific row
echo $data['meta_data'][2]['key']; // outputs: wf_invoice_number
```

To show the keys from a particular record, again at index 2:

```
#keys
printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( array_keys( $data['meta_data'][2] ), true ) );
```

To show the corresponding values at the same index:

```
#values
printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( array_values( $data['meta_data'][2] ), true ) );
```

Comment: The problem in this array is it is four time nested... Woocomerce respond in json and while decoding it in php we will found a four time nested array. So i use array_push t make an new array, and also push a value with key like :- $meta=array();
             foreach ($stdf as $key => $value) 
             {
              array_push($meta, $stdf[$key]['key']);
              $meta[$stdf[$key]['key']] = $stdf[$key]['value'];
             }
             
             $payment_details = $meta['payment_details'];....